# Access Database of Odoo 16 Enterprise to delete Records

Tags: postgresql, odoo

I have an enterprise version of odoo.I want to access it's database and want to delete some records using query as done using pgadmin.How to access the database for that ?

Comment: Depends on how your setup is. How is your setup?

Comment: Database is on odoo https://www.odoo.com/my/databases

Comment: I don't think you get direct database access on Odoo Online Hosting.

Comment: Which kind of record would you like to delete and why?

Comment: you need to contact Odoo directly for this since hosting is on Odoo